# Filtering QuerySet by __count of RelatedManager

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-related-manager

I've got a QuerySet I'd like to filter by the count of a `related_name`. Currently I've got something like this:

```
objResults = myObjects.filter(Q(links_by_source__status=ACCEPTED),Q(links_by_source__count=1))
```

However, when I run this I get the following error message:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'count' into field
```

I'm guessing that this query is operating individually on each of the `links_by_source` connections, therefore there is no `count` function since it's not a QuerySet I'm working with. Is there a way of filtering so that, for each object returned, the number of `links_by_source` is exactly 1?

Comment: `count` is field of your model ?

Comment: No, I was using it in the way that you'd use `objQuerySet.count()` on a query set.

Comment: There is no `__count` [field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) in Django querysets

Comment: I was wondering how I could get the functionality described in my question - to be able to filter by the number of objects in a foreign key relation. My inclusion of `__count` was just a guess, and I posted it here to demonstrate what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an aggregation function to get the count before you can filter on it.

```
from django.db.models import Count
myObjects.filter(
  links_by_source__status=ACCEPTED).annotate(link_count=Count('links_by_source')
).filter(link_count=1)
```

Note, you should pay attention to the [order of the annotate and filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) here: that query counts the number of ACCEPTED links, not sure if you want that or you want to check that the total count of *all* links is 1.

Comment: For some reason it's telling me that `links_by_source` is not defined.

Comment: Ah - it turns out that the relation name needs to be passed as a string. I'll accept your post but can't seem to make such a small edit to it - could you edit it so links_by_source is a string?